# NSFetchedResultsController, NSPredicate with [NSDate new]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a simple table that has an NSFetchedResultsController. It uses the current date to grab the content. My question is is there a way to have a dynamic NSPredicate so it is always the current date/time?

My NSPredicate is:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate new];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((transmission_time <= %@) && (%@ <= transmission_end_time))",now,now];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to represent the current date, but should your field type in your Coredata timestamp:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date] ;
```